# dplyr mutate ifelse returning first value of group instead of by-row

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to mutate a data.frame using ifelse:

```
df = data.frame(grp = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), 
                value1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2), 
                value2 = 1:6)


df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(all(value1 == 0), 0, value2))
```

which returns

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   grp [2]
#  grp   value1 value2
# <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a          0      0
# 2 a          0      0
# 3 a          0      0
# 4 b          0      4
# 5 b          1      4
# 6 b          2      4
```

instead of

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   grp [2]
#  grp   value1 value2
# <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a          0      0
# 2 a          0      0
# 3 a          0      0
# 4 b          0      4
# 5 b          1      5
# 6 b          2      6
```

How can I change the `mutate` so that the rows of "value2" are unchanged if the condition is false?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if` and `else` instead of `ifelse()`:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(grp) %>%
 mutate(value2 = if(all(value1 == 0)) 0 else value2)

  grp   value1 value2
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a          0      0
2 a          0      0
3 a          0      0
4 b          0      4
5 b          1      5
6 b          2      6
```

Comment: cool, didn't know they could be used like that inside mutate.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ifelse` as a mask, e.g.,

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(all(value1 == 0), 0, 1)*value2)
```

or (thank @tmfmnk's comment)

```
df %>%   
  group_by(grp) %>%  
  mutate(value2 = any(value1 != 0)*value2)
```

which gives

```
  grp   value1 value2
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a          0      0
2 a          0      0
3 a          0      0
4 b          0      4
5 b          1      5
6 b          2      6
```

---

The problem you encountered is due to the fact that `all(value1 == 0)` returns a single logical value. You need to have a vector of logic values to have your desired output, e.g.,

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(rep(all(value1 == 0),n()), 0, value2))
```

Comment: In that case, `df %>% 
 group_by(grp) %>%
 mutate(value2 = any(value1 != 0)*value2)` would be more reasonable, wouldn't it?

Comment: @tmfmnk Yes, it is more reasonable.